# RoboVM: How to use iOS SWRevealViewController library for using SlideMenu in the storyboard?

Tags: java, ios, xcode, intellij-idea, robovm

I am trying to use the SlideMenu in RoboVM-iOS project with SWRevealViewController library.
I added and used this library into the xCode project for building the storyboard but it shows "Unknown class SWRevealViewController in Interface Builder file." error when compiling the RoboVM project. I am using IntelliJ-14 for RoboVM project.

Comment: Add the code which you have tried in the question for a better understanding

Comment: Actually, I haven't added any codes regarding the SWRevealViewController library and just used it on xCode storyboard. 
I tried to add this library manually into the only xCode.

Comment: Thank you. By the way, do you know how to use native iOS third party libraries in RoboVM project?